# Render Rtf text stored in database as bytes using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll to word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing Rtf text from Windows RichTextBox control as Bytes into Database.

I want to Render that Rtf data stored in the database to Word using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll.

How to render Rtf data into work document.

Comment: Are you doing using the Interop.Word dll in ASP.NET?

Comment: yes i am using  Interop.Word dll in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Not even Microsoft recommends using Office Automation in ASP.NET (see [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) MSDN reference).

You could use the OOXML library, found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en).  There is also (not free) [Aspose.words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).

Comment: Ok , what if i have to use the same thing in the windows application and use the Rtf in the word document generation.